# As2: onPress function looped through all instances

Tags: flash, function, actionscript-2

Im writing a game in Actionsctipt2 and ive got problem while clicking enemy.
It should decrement HP of the movieClip clicked. Instead it decrements always HP of the first (z1). What is wrong with my code?

```
for(i=1;i<3;i++){
        targetx = _root.otoczenie._x + _root.otoczenie["z"+i]._x;
        targety = _root.otoczenie._y + _root.otoczenie["z"+i]._y;
        _root.otoczenie["z"+i].onPress = function()
        {
                bullet--;
                _root.clip.bullets.text = String(bullet);
                SHOT_SOUND();
                _root.postac.gotoAndStop(33);
                trace(_root.otoczenie["z1"].HP)
                trace(_root.otoczenie["z2"].HP);
                     if (CHECK_RANGE(targetx, targety, 400))
                {
                    HP("z"+i,-1);
                }
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is HP("z"+i,-1); ?
Its not  HP -= _root.otoczenie["z"+i].hp;?

I think you need to subtracted the array HP from the total hp?  Is this for the main player or the enemy unit?  If HP is a function, what is inside that function?